# Estimate function range numerically

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow A $, what are some ways I can estimate $A$ numerically, without any assumptions on $f$?

A naive approach would be to sample some points $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and then compute repeatedly $f(x)$.

Are there more efficient approaches?

Comment: A substantial part of this problem is identifying local/global extrema of $f$.

Comment: No, not without any assumptions on $f$. You do not even have continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $B$ is
*any* set of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ (the same cardinality as the set real numbers). Then there is a bijection $g:\Bbb R\to B.$ Random sampling of $x\in\Bbb R$ to see what $g(x)$ is will tell you almost nothing about $B$.

Now suppose that $C$ is any countably-infinite set, and fix some $y\in C.$ Take any bijection $h:\Bbb Z\to C,$ and then extend it to a function $p:\Bbb R\to C$ by letting $p(x)=h(x)$ for $x\in\Bbb Z,$ and $p(x)=y,$ otherwise. Then $p$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ onto $C,$ but it's constant, except on a set of measure zero, so random sampling would be very unlikely to reveal its true nature.

You'll want a codomain--to know that $B$ is a subset of something familiar, ideally with a metric or topology so that you have some notion of continuity--or you're pretty much going to be completely in the dark about the range of an arbitrary function on $\Bbb R.$